# C# Why cant I add more items to a list of strings? I can add a singular item

Tags: c#

```
private List<string> _listOfWords = new List<string>();

 _listOfWords.Add("tell", "hey"); 

//Why does not this work? I can add one item but not multiple
```

Comment: There isn’t an overload for that

Comment: Because that's how the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-6.0) method works.. Always check the documentation when you aren't sure/familiar with how a method works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`List<T>.Add(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-6.0) only accepts a single parameter.

So multiple items can be added by call the method multiple times like

```
list.Add("item1");
list.Add("item2");
```

or you can use another method like [`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0) to add multiple items in a single call

```
list.AddRange(new string[] { "item1", "item", ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking perhaps for `AddRange`?

```
_listOfWords.AddRange(new[] { "tell", "hey" });
```